# selectize.js total seems to be ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

See the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh6Nx/2/)

Total number of expected results is 3 but it seems to be ignored?

```
$('#itemlocationcity').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    total:3,
    searchField: 'item'
});
```